# In Groovy -in the list of array How to fill empty fields in version with number zero?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

In groovy, How to add zero in empty fields of versions in list

```
def list = [1.0,
1.9,
1.11.0,
1.6,
1.7,
1.7.1,
1.8]
```

**Expected Output**

```
1.0.0,
1.9.0,
1.11.0,
1.6.0,
1.7.0,
1.7.1,
1.8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show there is not valid Groovy code and will not compile. You can not define a number like `1.11.0`.  That would have to be a String.

The following generates your desired output for that specific data input:

```
def list = ['1.0',
            '1.9',
            '1.11.0',
            '1.6',
            '1.7',
            '1.7.1',
            '1.8']

println list.collect {
    String output = it
    if(output.count('.') < 2) output += '.0'
    output
}.join(',\n')
```

Could also do it like this:

```
def list = ['1.0',
            '1.9',
            '1.11.0',
            '1.6',
            '1.7',
            '1.7.1',
            '1.8']

println list.collect {
    if(it.count('.') < 2) it += '.0'
    it
}.join(',\n')
```

Or this:

```
def list = ['1.0',
            '1.9',
            '1.11.0',
            '1.6',
            '1.7',
            '1.7.1',
            '1.8']

println list.collect {
    it.count('.') < 2 ? it += '.0' : it
}.join(',\n')
```